# Will a keystroke I pressed during sleep get executed afterwards?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine I have some program to measure my reaction time, in which it sleeps for a random amount of seconds and after that, it displays a message to tell me I have to press a key. It seems that if I press a key during time.sleep(x), the keystroke will be recorded and "executed" right afterwards. Am I right?

Comment: when you say "executed", what statement are you using to test whether a key is pressed?

Comment: Basically sleep, start timer, press key for input, stop timer, display time. And if I pressed a key while it was sleeping, I didn't need to press anything again, it automatically took that key as input when it reached that part of the code

Comment: The point of @alaniwi's question is that there's more than one way to read from a keyboard and the results will depend on which way you use.  For ordinary buffered terminal input, I would expect the behavior you have reported.  There are probably lower-level, platform-dependent alternatives that might, for example, send you separate events when a key was pressed and when it was released.  If your question is whether the behavior you observed is normal or due to a defect in your software, it's probably normal.

Comment: I see, thanks for the further clarification